# How to do real-time video streaming frame by frame in python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

What I need is to readin one frame of a video, then send this frame as a frame in video, like P-frame, to the server, and server decode it based on the information of the frames it received before this frame.(So only the first frame is sent as complete I-frame, the rest are just P-frame to save bandwidth)

Then I need to do some real time operation on this frame.

But I try ffmpeg's and opencv's built in streaming protocal, it can only save a complete video file. But I need to do some real time manipulate as soon as I receive one fram, so I cant wait till I have received the whole file.

So what package should I use? Or there is not existing lib/software that could do this?

Comment: What kind of real time operation are you applying to the frame?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/604859

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/Extracting-I-P-B-frames-from-a-mpg-video-td4668751.html

Comment: I am building a client that capture video and streaming it to server. Server run a detection on each frame as soon as it receive enough data to decode it. And the client also needs to receive the detection result from the server.

Comment: So what I need is not to decode the video and extract I-frame and P-frame as image file from a video file, but to extract the meta data of this frame and send these metadata to server, and server decode these meta data of one frame as soon as it got enough information about that frame.